# Call manager of select_related field

Tags: django

I have the following example:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...

class Person(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, ...)
```

I have complex Model manager for Profile class and I built a view to list a big amount of Person. I try to compute everything in database so I would like to call the Profile Manager from Person QuerySet.

To do that, I need to do something like:

```
Person.objects.filter(...).select_related('profile', queryset=Profile.objects.with_computed_revenue().all())
```

And then I should be able to get person.profile.computed_revenue retrieved from SQL, with the function "with_computed_revenue" being a function of the ProfileManager that annotate computed_revenue.

The final goal is to add in person queryset :

```
.values('profile__computed_revenue')
```

It seems possible with Prefetch for prefetch_related, but I cannot find an equivalent with select_related.

Comment: Do you have ```related_name='profile'``` in your ```Person``` model?

Comment: Can you share the "with_computed_revenue" method and relevant fields on the Profile model? Using select_related this way I'm not sure is possible

Comment: If you can live without values() working the way you want this is possible with Prefetch and a custom queryset

Comment: I agree with you lain, I think the way I want it is not possible. with_computed_revenue is an annotation with complex Case / When and various condition (it's like 400 lines). Do you know to make Prefetch works with a ForeignKey relation ? I get this error: 'Profile' object has no attribute '_iterable_class'

Comment: @QuentinMortier added an answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

If i have got correctly what you mean, As Django docs says in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related :

> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason, select_related gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related.

You should use `select_related` for FK relations and `prefetch_related` for Many-To-One relation

In your case, `Person` model has many-to-one relation to `Profile`, thus you have to use `prefetch_related`

Comment: I agree with that indeed, it should be prefetch_related. But when using it you get an error: .prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'profile',
                queryset=Profile.objects.with_computed_revenue().all().first(),
                to_attr='computed_profile'
            )
        )  this will give: 'Profile' object has no attribute '_iterable_class'

Comment: And prefetch related won't allow me to use values('profile__anything') right ?

Answer (score 1):

To use a custom queryset with `select_related` you can use prefetch_related and a Prefetch object

```
Person.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('profile', queryset=Profile.objects.with_computed_revenue())
)
```

This will not make the annotations available in values() however